# How to pass a global variable to a function which is called by another function

Tags: python, function, global-variables

Given below example, I want to figure out what causes the exception of 
`"NameError: global name 'MATRIX' is not defined"` when executing `test.fun1()`.

Thanks a lot.

```
class test:
    MATRIX = []

    @staticmethod        
    def fun1():
        global MATRIX
        test.fun2(MATRIX)

    @staticmethod
    def fun2(MATRIX):
        MATRIX.append(2)

test.fun1()    
print test.MATRIX
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MATRIX` is not global, it's a class attribute, try like this:

```
class test:
    MATRIX = []

    @classmethod     # Note classmethod, not staticmethod   
    def fun1(cls):   # cls will be test here
        test.fun2(cls.MATRIX)

    @staticmethod
    def fun2(MATRIX):
        MATRIX.append(2)

test.fun1()    
print test.MATRIX
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it helped me understand what an real global variable is.

Answer (score 2):

The error `"NameError: global name 'MATRIX' is not defined"` is caused because there is not a global variable named MATRIX in your code.

In your code *MATRIX* is not a global variable but a a class attribute. A global variable would be used something like this:

```
MATRIX = []

class test:

    @staticmethod
    def fun1():
        test.fun2(MATRIX)

    @staticmethod
    def fun2(l):
        l.append(2)

    @staticmethod
    def reset():
        global MATRIX
        MATRIX = []

test.fun1()
print MATRIX
# >>> [2]
test.fun1()
print MATRIX
# >>> [2, 2]
test.reset()
print MATRIX
# >>> []
```

Comment: This doesn't achieve what the title of the question asks. He wants to pass a global variable to a function called by another function, you have moved the global declaration into the called function.

Comment: `global MATRIX` isn't needed there. You only need it if you want to assign a new object to a global variable (as in: `MATRIX = ...`).